# SQL Query: Counters and percentages

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table where i store all product orders.
I need to count the number of closed and failed orders grouped by dealer and months and the percentage of failed orders and the number requests of extra info .

Table looks like this:

```
order id | status | dealer_id | month | area | requests
    1      Closed       1         4       N   "extra info"
    2      failed       2         4       S   "extra info"
    3      failed       2         4       S       0
```

The sample result set would be:

```
    dealer |  month  |  Total |  % Failed |  Requested info 
       1        4         1         0              0
       2        4         2        100 %           1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query seems to work, using SQLite on Linux:

```
    SELECT a.dealer_id AS dealer, a.month, COUNT(*) AS total,
            (SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM orders b
            WHERE b.dealer_id=a.dealer_id
            AND b.month=a.month
            AND b.status!='Closed')*100/COUNT(*) AS failed
    FROM orders a
    GROUP BY a.dealer_id, a.month;
```

Please check if that works for your requirements and give feedback!

Comment: Great. Forgot to include the last col but managed by myself.
Thanks!

Comment: Oh, right, sorry forgot to include it, but of course the principle is the same ;-)